# Docker Hub timeout in automated build

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I'm using automated build to create docker images for a benchmark suite. In one of the benchmarks, which is web search, I have to use a very big index file (11GB). My image is not being built, and I'm receiving this error :`The build has timed out.`

But when I check the build log, which is very long, in the last line I can see that it has actually built successfully: `Successfully built 4c84c7ec04c6`

It seems that the worker responsible for creating this image, loses its connection with its master (registry node), while it is still processing and building the image. It's probably due to the fact that it takes a couple of hours to download the index file.

What can I do to prevent this from happening?

For more information, you can check the build log [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/cloudsuite/web-search/builds/bjprlfzauigahk9sj4vt5zu/).

Thanks.

Comment: For issues with automated builds, it's best to contact support@docker.com. They should be able to look into your issue.

Comment: Haha, with the way people "manage" the internet today, links don't even last 4 years. Not just the build log, but the whole project URL is dead.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've contacted their support team, and according to their response, the current limits on Automated Builds are:

- 2 hours
- 2 GB RAM
- 1 CPU
- 30 GB Disk Space

So, for larger builds you have to either break them into several Automated Builds connected by `FROM` statements and Repository Links, or build them locally on your machine and push them to the repository.

Comment: sadly opencv3.4 is taking longer than that to build...(at least with gpu support)

Comment: I think the timeout limit is much higher now. I had an Automated Build running that timed out after 9 hours.